# what process is listening on a given port

Tags: iptables, lsof, netstat

I have several problems:

1. some process is attempting to send data and the firewall is rejecting it at the rate it is sending it out
2. firewall logs flood the system (may need to rate-limit the logging)
3. lsof -i :port does not list the process, but there has to be something causing the packets to keep being sent.  netstat -patune lists it in the SYN_SENT state not listening

The port that it is using does not make sense to me so that is one oddity and the other being how traffic continues to be sent.

Comment: If you have nethog installed does it show the egressing traffic?

Comment: Make up your mind: **Either** the process is sending (SYN) data **or** it is listening on a port (then it would be receiving data and easily be seen with `netstat`). Probably the question title is wrong.

Comment: exactly what rule is triggered in the firewall?

Comment: For example: `sudo nethogs wlp3s0` to listen on my wifi.

Comment: Next strange point: `netstat -patune` **does** show the process. Even in `SYN_SENT` state.

Comment: Is it your web browser by chance? If you turn it off does it subside?

Comment: no, this is a headless box

Comment: my mind is made up ... read carefully, I said it is NOT listening in netstat, it shows the state as SYN_SENT ...

Comment: nethogs isn't showing the PID nor the port (it says unknown tcp)

Comment: You might find a clue about this via `cat /etc/services | grep [port number]`.

Comment: well, the temporary solution was to take the interfaces down and back up, that appeared to kill whatever was sending the packets

Comment: By `[port number]` I meant, the destination, presuming by deduction that your title is actually a misnomer *(it's not **listening,** it's trying to connect).*

Comment: Ah, yes, it is/was trying to connect, but I'm still not sure what was trying to connect.  I would think you'd have to see it with netstat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't resolve what was trying to connect, but what killed whatever process was trying to connect was simply ifconfig interface_name down.

Comment: Actually, it appears to have been something from my NFS server.  I never had this problem before, but I'm on a different linux distribution so perhaps the difference in configuration is coming into play.

Answer (score 2):

To check which programs is listening on a port.

The command netstat has options to show listened ports and programs/pids, I usually disable DNS look up as well.

`netstat -nlp`

or just tcp ports

`netstat -nltp`

`man netstat` for further reading and all options.